# Reducing a list of sets to minimum by intersecting them

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of sets (generated from a list of ranges) (eg. [1,3] -> {1,2,3}). Then I need to reduce this list of sets by taking intersections. Two sets are reduced to their intersection. I need to find the minimum number of elements that will be left if I completely reduce this list of sets, generated from the list of ranges provided in input.

input 1: X number of sets
input 2 : Array consisting of x pairs, each pair indicating start and end of a set

Eg 1:
input 1: 3
input 2: [[1,3],[2,5],[3,6]]
output : 1 (All the above mentioned sets can be reduced to 1 minimum point 3)

Eg 2:
input 1: 3
input 2: [[1,3],[2,5],[6,9]]
output : 2 (All the above mentioned sets can be reduced to 2 minimum points 2 and 6)

```
def mini(input1,input2):
    a = set()
    b=set()
    c=set()
    for i in input2:
        for j in range(i[0],i[1]+1):
            if i==input2[0]:
                a.add(j)
            elif i==input2[1]:
                b.add(j)
            else:
                c.add(j)
    d = []
    if (a.intersection(b,c)):
        d.append(a.intersection(b,c))
    elif(a.intersection(b)):
        d.append(a.intersection(b))
        d.append(min(c))
    return len(d)
        
print(mini(3,[[1,3],[2,5],[3,6]]))
```

This code works for the given input but if the number of sets are changed this wont work.
I need to write an code for this without using modules. Can anyone help me in this please.

Comment: You've hardcoded the use of 3 sets by limiting yourself to `a`, `b`, and `c` and storing the input in only those 3 variables. Furthermore, your set intersections only consider the upper and lower bounds, so you haven't really solved the problem you've been given. You really need to consider the given inputs as ranges not python [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) data structures.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please improve the definition of the problem? What do you mean by "If a point is plotted between any set, that set is reduced to that point"?

Comment: Please find my answer to your problem. Can work on any number of sets provided and uses recursion to reduce the sets until they cant be reduced further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interesting problem to solve, wish you had articulated it better. But here is the solution.

In a nutshell -

1. It creates a list of sets based on any number of ranges provided in
   input2
2. It recursively reduces the first 2 elements of this list to
   their intersection until there is nothing left to reduce
3. It calculates the length of the final reduced list and returns the list too

Please find inline comments for better understanding.

```
def f(input2):
    s = [set(range(i[0],i[1]+1)) for i in input2]  #Creates list of sets based on ranges in input2
    s = g(s)   #Calls the recursive function g
    mini = len(s)  #length of reduced set
    reduced = [set([min(i)]) for i in s] #final reduced items
    return mini,reduced

#Recursive function that RECURSIVELY takes first 2 elements of the list of sets, 
#reduces them to the set of their intersection until the list has a single set or
#doesnt have any intersection left between elements
def g(s):
    if len(s)>1:
        if s[0].intersection(s[1]):
            s = s[2:]+[s[0].intersection(s[1])]
            return g(s)
        else:
            return s
    else:
        return s
```

```
input2 = [[1,3],[2,5],[6,9],[7,9],[10,12]]
mini, reduced = f(input2)
print(mini)
```

```
3
```

```
print(reduced)
```

```
[{10}, {2}, {7}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Akshay Sehgal. It solved my problem. Much appreciated..